# Excel automation - set cell font

Tags: vba, delphi, excel, c++builder-xe4

This is my original code for setting content of Excel sheet. In short, the code iterates through all rows and columns and set three things: cell content, cell font color and cell background color:

```
Excel_xp::ExcelApplicationPtr app = excel->Application;
app->set_ScreenUpdating(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, TVariant(false));

Excel_xp::ExcelRangePtr cells = worksheet->Cells;
cells->Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
{
   CsvLine *line = lines[i];
   int col_count = line->GetColCount();
   for (int j = 0; j < col_count; j++)
   {
      CsvLine::Data data;
      line->GetData(j, data);
      TVariant _cell = cells->get_Item(TVariant(i+1), TVariant(j+1));
      IDispatch *__cell = (IDispatch*)_cell;
      Excel_xp::ExcelRange *cell = NULL;
      if (__cell->QueryInterface(DIID_ExcelRange, (void**)&cell) != S_OK)
      {
         __cell->Release();
         __cell->Release();
         __cell = NULL;
         continue;
      }

      cell->set_Item(TVariant(1), TVariant(1), TVariant(data.str));

      TColor font_color, back_color;
      if (data.good || ((!data.good) && (!highlight_bad_values)))
      {
         font_color = (TColor)0;
         back_color = (TColor)-4142;
      }
      else
      {
         font_color = (TColor)0x06009C;
         back_color = (TColor)0xCEC7FF;
      }
      Excel_xp::FontPtr font = cell->Font;
      font->set_Color(TVariant(font_color));
      font->Release();
      font = (IUnknown*)NULL;
      Excel_xp::InteriorPtr back = cell->Interior;
      back->set_Color(TVariant(back_color));
      back->Release();
      back = (IUnknown*)NULL;

      cell->Release();
      cell->Release();
      cell->Release();
      cell = NULL;
   }
}
```

Previous code even when functionally OK had one drawback namely speed. Every call of function from COM interface has some overhead (cca 1 - 3 ms). To generate sheet consisting of 900 rows x 6 columns I needed around 38 seconds which was unacceptable in comparison with performance of todays computets. So I optimized the code. Instead of setting cell by cell I first prepared the whole data in memory in one big array and set content of whole sheet in one step. Later I can optimize it further to minimize memory requirements of my application. I can limit the maximum number of rows written in one step for example to 100. But this is irrelevant to my problem. This is my optimized code:

```
Excel_xp::ExcelApplicationPtr app = excel->Application;
app->set_ScreenUpdating(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, TVariant(false));

Excel_xp::ExcelRangePtr cells = worksheet->Cells;
cells->Clear();

int bounds[] = {1, lines.size(), 1, GetMaxColCount()};
Variant arr_text = VarArrayCreate(bounds, 3, varVariant);
int line_count = lines.size();
int arr_idx[2];
for (int i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
{
   arr_idx[0] = i + 1;
   CsvLine *line = lines[i];
   int col_count = line->GetColCount();
   for (int j = 0; j < col_count; j++)
   {
      arr_idx[1] = j + 1;
      CsvLine::Data data;
      line->GetData(j, data);
      VarArrayPut(arr_text, TVariant(data.str), arr_idx, 1);      
   }
}
TVariant _cell1 = cells->get_Item(TVariant(1), TVariant(1));   // ref_count = 1
TVariant _cell2 = cells->get_Item(TVariant(bounds[1]), TVariant(bounds[3]));   // ref_count = 1
Excel_xp::ExcelRangePtr rng = cells->get_Range(_cell1, _cell2);
_cell1 = NULL;
_cell2 = NULL;

rng->set_Value2(arr_text);
arr_text.Clear();
rng->Release();
rng = (IUnknown*)NULL;
```

Now I am trying to use the same mechanism for cell font. Is it possible to prepare font color array (where every cell can use different color) and set it for worksheet in one call ?

P.S. The answer should be preferably in C++ but can be also in Delphi.

Comment: No, it isn't. What you can do is create one `Range` object that refers to all the cells of interest and then set that Range's colours as you need in one go. I don't know what you'd use in Delphi but in Excel VBA it would be the `Union` method of the `Excel.Application` object.

Comment: If you are true, then it would help me, if I could define range which is not continuous for example A1 + B2 + D5 + F4 + ... in one call and then set common font for these cells in second call. Two calls would be perfectly OK, but not the count that linearly depends on size of data.

Comment: what do you use Excel for ? can you just save the table into file and open it into Excel by ShellExecute ?

Comment: > range which is not continuous 

there should be a way... `.Selected` is range and you can select several non-adjacent cells by ctrl+click

Comment: there also some ExcelApplication global settings like prohibiting events and prohibiting sheet redrawing and recalculation, so you might suppress those intermediate processes until you would finish all the colourings

Comment: @Arioch: I cannot use ctrl+click, because the excel application is not visible. I control it through COM interface. If you read code excerpt you will see, that I forbid screen redrawing.

Comment: You can ctrl-Click in user-launched excel and then ask for VBA-code for that sequence to re-write it into C++/Delphi
////
OTOH I think while doing it via selections is possible, hardly would be a good solution. I just mentioned the ctrl+click as a proof that it should be possible to make non-continuos ranges as Excel itself does it often

Comment: @Rory has the correct idea here.  Excel is very proficient at dealing with ranges of cells at once.  You can build the range using `Union` like `rng_union = Union(rng_union, rng_next_cell_to_add)` or you can build a giant string of addresses joining with a comma and then call `get_Range` and let Excel figure that out (C# can deal with a string parameter).  `Union` should be faster and is cleaner.

Comment: @Byron well, I'd try to ditch of Excel interop completely for "faster and cleaner" solution :-)